# How to build such environment with turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, reinforcement-learning, python-turtle

I'm trying to apply reinforcement learning on a specifique problem and I'm trying to buid my environment with turtle. however when I am doing it I got different shapes eventhough there should be juste two shapes.[the environment consists of two machine each should be able to rotate 90° degree as much as we want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsOKt.png)

```
import turtle

win = turtle.Screen()    # Create a screen
win.title('Facilities layout problem')      # Set the title to paddle
win.bgcolor('black')     # Set the color to black
win.tracer(0)
win.setup(width=600, height=600)   # Set the width and height to 600


# first machine
machine1 = turtle.Turtle()    # Create a turtle object
machine1.shape('square')      # Select a square shape
machine1.speed(0)
machine1.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=5)   # Streach the length of square by 5
machine1.penup()
machine1.color('white')       # Set the color to white
machine1.goto(-100, 0)        # Place the shape on bottom of the screen

# pickup point for machine 1
pickup_m1 = turtle.Turtle()    # Create a turtle object
pickup_m1.shape('triangle')      # Select a square shape
pickup_m1.speed(0)
pickup_m1.shapesize(stretch_wid=1, stretch_len=1)   # Streach the length of square by 5
pickup_m1.penup()
pickup_m1.color('blue')       # Set the color to white
pickup_m1.goto(-140, -30)        # Place the shape on bottom of the screen
pickup_m1.tilt(180)

# delivery point for machine 1
delivery_m1 = turtle.Turtle()    # Create a turtle object
delivery_m1.shape('triangle')      # Select a square shape
delivery_m1.speed(0)
delivery_m1.shapesize(stretch_wid=1, stretch_len=1)   # Streach the length of square by 5
delivery_m1.penup()
delivery_m1.color('green')       # Set the color to white
delivery_m1.goto(-144, 30)        # Place the shape on bottom of the screen


# second machine
machine2 = turtle.Turtle()    # Create a turtle object
machine2.shape('square')      # Select a square shape
machine2.speed(0)
machine2.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=5)   # Streach the length of square by 5
machine2.penup()
machine2.color('white')       # Set the color to white
machine2.goto(100, 0)        # Place the shape on bottom of the screen

# pickup point for machine 2
pickup_m2 = turtle.Turtle()    # Create a turtle object
pickup_m2.shape('triangle')      # Select a square shape
pickup_m2.speed(0)
pickup_m2.shapesize(stretch_wid=1, stretch_len=1)   # Streach the length of square by 5
pickup_m2.penup()
pickup_m2.color('blue')       # Set the color to white
pickup_m2.goto(60, -30)        # Place the shape on bottom of the screen
pickup_m2.tilt(180)

# delivery point for machine 2
delivery_m2 = turtle.Turtle()    # Create a turtle object
delivery_m2.shape('triangle')      # Select a square shape
delivery_m2.speed(0)
delivery_m2.shapesize(stretch_wid=1, stretch_len=1)   # Streach the length of square by 5
delivery_m2.penup()
delivery_m2.color('green')       # Set the color to white
delivery_m2.goto(56, 30)        # Place the shape on bottom of the screen

machine1.right(90)

while True:
     win.update()        # Show the scree continuously
```

Comment: `while True: win.update()` isn't a good pattern. This just slams the CPU as hard as possible. Better to use `ontimer` to run your update loop. Beyond that, I'm not sure what you're asking here. Can you clarify what the problem is? Thanks

Comment: Thank you of your answer. I have linked a picture of what I want to get(clic on the underlined text). I have two machines each of them has pickup and delivery point which are represented by triangles. I have created the machine with rectangles and the point with triangles but those shapes are sperated so when I try to rotate a machine is just the rectangle who rotate and not the two point.

Comment: How can I create shapes that present exactly the machines presented in the picture